# Font scaling based on width of container in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, font-size, font-scaling

How can one scale a block of text (with font-scaling) in Bootstrap Framework?

[image: how to scale a block of text]

Width of columns is the main difficulty, because it's fluid.

Comment: I've tried to implement that using [Viewport Percentage Units](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container). But I suppose that the solution depends on javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap use CSS @media for Grid system [[link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)] so you can use media queries with Bootstrap's dimensions to set another CSS properties. Check out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z2q0o79h/) and resize the bar between js and display window to see the effect of header font-size changing.

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="header">header</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="colDiv col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <p>ColumnA</p>
    </div>
    <div class="colDiv col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
      <p>ColumnB</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

ok so I wrote a little little JS function to do that.
You set six parameters (in order) to manipulate the fontSize:

```
alignFont(getElement,defaultSize,defaultWidth,acceleration,min,max)
```

- **getElement** - set element the font-size you want to manipulate within
- **defaultSize** - the default (start) size of font
- **defaultWidth** - the width of window for which the defaultSize of font is set
- **acceleration** - 1 is normal, 2 - increase two times faster, .5 - increase slower
- **min** - the minimal fontSize (the font size cannot be smaller than this value)
- **max** - the maximal fontSize (the font size cannot be higher than this value)

And the example *(resize the bar between js box and display box)*: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9gtn230k/)

```js
    var a = document.getElementById('flexibleHeaderA');
    var b = document.getElementById('flexibleHeaderB');
    var c = document.getElementById('flexibleHeaderC');
    var d = document.getElementById('flexibleHeaderD');
    var e = document.getElementById('flexibleHeaderE');

    var settingA = alignFont.bind(this, a, 24, 600, 1, 20, 30);
    var settingB = alignFont.bind(this, b, 24, 600, 1.5, 12, 60);
    var settingC = alignFont.bind(this, c, 30, 600, 1, 15, 35);
    var settingD = alignFont.bind(this, d, 22, 1000, .5, 12, 30);
    var settingE = alignFont.bind(this, e, 16, 80, 1, 12, 26);

    settingA();
    settingB();
    settingC();
    settingD();
    settingE();

    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
      settingA();
      settingB();
      settingC();
      settingD();
      settingE();
    });


    function alignFont(getElement, defaultSize, defaultWidth, acceleration, min, max) {
      var cWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;
      var newSize = (Math.pow(cWidth / defaultWidth, acceleration)) * defaultSize;
      var limitSize = newSize >= max ? max : newSize <= min ? min : newSize;
      getElement.style.fontSize = limitSize + "px";
    }
```

```css
h3 {
  border: dotted 1px #33aaff;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h3 id="flexibleHeaderA">Hello I'm flexible header</h3>
<h3 id="flexibleHeaderB">Hello I'm flexible header</h3>
<h3 id="flexibleHeaderC">Hello I'm flexible header</h3>
<h3 id="flexibleHeaderD">Hello I'm flexible header</h3>
<h3 id="flexibleHeaderE">Hello I'm flexible header</h3>
```

Comment: The problem is the text block (text + container) has a fluid width. So I need a font-scaling — `font-size` shouldn't be strictly defined.

Comment: I've just edited post. Not sure if I explained it clear so ask if you've got any questions.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot!